# Is "After which amount I need to check their ID?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

If I work as a bank teller, and my manger ask me to check customer's ID when they withdraw large amount of cash. If I want to know what does he mean by large amount, is it correct to say:

> "After which amount I need to check their ID?"

Comment: 'More than what amount' is better than 'which amount' because which implies pre-existing options.

Answer (score 2):

Using your sentence structure:

> What is the amount *above which* I should check their ID?

Alternative ways of asking:

casual:

> When is the amount big enough that I should check their ID?

polite:

> Could you please tell me what amount you have in mind when you say "large"?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

> **What sum** / **amount** of money do I **start checking** clients' IDs?

You need to know *when* to begin checking clients identification records before handing over  large (‘significant’)  sums of money.